# Limiting the maximum length of a string

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I need to prevent a string from exceeding a certain length and, if it does, truncate the last part of the string.

I'm using `GUI.TextField` to get the string from the user.

Comment: If your UI element has a maxlength property, use that. Otherwise validate the length and/or use stringValue.Substring(0, desiredLength) if it exceeds your limit.

Comment: @chris you should make that an answer

Comment: @Kevin, Just did. I'm not familiar with Unity, and it took me a little bit to realize that the Unity tag meant I should be searching that instead of Windows Forms or something :p I also called it a constructor before I realized it was a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it with a property to handle truncation:

```
public SomeClass {
    private const int MaxLength = 20; // for example
    private String _theString;

    public String CappedString {
        get { return _theString; }
        set {
            _theString = value != null && value.Length > MaxLength
                ? value.Substring(0, MaxLength)
                : value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can apply this in whatever class needs to implement it.  Just carry over the `private` field, the constant, and the property `CappedString`.

Comment: Careful in that setter. If I send in "hello world", the truncation will fall on its head.

Comment: @user414076 is right.  Your setter needs a check on the length of the string, otherwise it will fail if the length of the string is less than 20.  Probably not what OP wanted

Comment: The basic concept of this worked for me i just changed around and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

`GUI.TextField` lets you pass a max length in. You have two to choose from:

```
static function TextField (position : Rect, text : String, maxLength : int) : String
static function TextField (position : Rect, text : String, maxLength : int, style : GUIStyle) : String
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest it can get, because I was able to fit it into one line.

```
(([STRING].Length > [MAX-LENGTH(int)]) ? [STRING].Substring(0, [MAX-LENGTH(int)]) : [STRING])
```

So as an explaination, first it checks if the string is longer than 10 characters, if so it limits the string with Substring and if not, it just takes the whole string.

Some brackets may be unnecessary, but for my purposes, it was what I needed.

Anyways, hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I hope to see more answers from you in the future.